# Laravel Eloquent sum of multiplied columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table named `transactions` in mysql database and I am going to use Laravel's Eloquent ORM (Laravel 5) to get sum of multiplied column (jumlah) and (harga), this what my table looks alike:

```
+----+----------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | nama_barang | jumlah | harga   | keterangan | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 |        3 | PS 4        |      2 | 4500000 | Hitam      | 2015-05-20 08:55:26 | 2015-05-20 08:56:14 |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And I want to get result something like this:

```
select sum(jumlah * harga) from transactions;
+---------------------+
| sum(jumlah * harga) |
+---------------------+
|             9000000 |
+---------------------+
```

How to do that with ORM Laravel, I tried this one, but it gives me `0`:

```
$amount = Transaction::all()->sum('(jumlah * harga)');
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try use this

```
$amount = Transaction::select(DB::raw('sum(jumlah * harga) as total'))->get();
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';' I think it needs a closing bracket.

Comment: $count = Transaction::select(DB::raw('SUM(x * y) AS count'))->get()->sum('count')'

Answer (score 20):

Eloquent style is as below:

```
$amount = Transaction::all()->sum(function($t){ 
    return $t->jumlah * $t->harga; 
});
```

Comment: This is slower than doing the sum in the query. Check my answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
$amount = Transaction::sum(\DB::raw('jumla * harga'));
```

This is more Eloquently done. In short, it's fast.

Another example:

```
$order_total = $order->products()->sum(\DB::raw('order_product.price * order_product.quantity'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $particulars =DB::table('particulars as A')
        ->leftjoin('reqs as B', function ($join) {
            $join->on('A.particular_id', '=', 'B.particular_id');
        })
        ->whereBetween('B.date_issued', [$start_date, $end_date])
        ->select('A.item_name','A.unit','A.price','B.quantity_issued',DB::raw('sum(A.price*B.quantity_issued) as total_cost'))
        ->groupBy('A.particular_id')
        ->get();
```

use something like this by using placing your table name

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Laravel accessor

> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
public function getTotalAttribute()
{
    return $this->all()->sum(function($transaction){
        return $transaction->jumlah * $transaction->harga; 
    });
}
At the top of your Order model put
protected $appends = ['total'];
you can get total like this (new Transaction)->total;
```

Comment: This would retrieve every column of every record in the table, and then loop through every one of them one by one adding up the bits you're after. This is not the way.

Comment: @Healyhatman I read the question again this is the solution I think for this question. But yes we can customize the query as per your need using where and first chain method.

Comment: The solution below by doncadavona frin 2018 is exactly what the OP was after :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in 2 steps

First, get the sums

```
$transaction = Transaction::select(\DB::raw('SUM(jumlah) as jumlak, SUM(harga) as harga'))
->first()
```

Then do the multiplication

```
$amount = $transaction->jumlah * $transaction->harga;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the result would be quite different then.

(a * b) + (c * d) is not equal to (a + c) * (b + d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectRaw without calling DB in Laravel 8

```
 $amount = Transaction::selectRaw('sum(jumlah * harga) as total')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `DB::raw` method here:

```
Transaction::all()->select(DB::raw('sum(jumlah * harga) AS sum_of_jumlah_harga'))
```

Comment: This also give me error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select()